# Minimal Cocoa application - problem with menu

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I need to implement minimal Cocoa application without Xcode. I am trying this example:

https://www.cocoawithlove.com/2010/09/minimalist-cocoa-programming.html

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

int main()
{
    [NSAutoreleasePool new];
    [NSApplication sharedApplication];
    [NSApp setActivationPolicy:NSApplicationActivationPolicyRegular];
    id menubar = [[NSMenu new] autorelease];
    id appMenuItem = [[NSMenuItem new] autorelease];
    [menubar addItem:appMenuItem];
    [NSApp setMainMenu:menubar];
    id appMenu = [[NSMenu new] autorelease];
    id appName = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] processName];
    id quitTitle = [@"Quit " stringByAppendingString:appName];
    id quitMenuItem = [[[NSMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:quitTitle
        action:@selector(terminate:) keyEquivalent:@"q"] autorelease];
    [appMenu addItem:quitMenuItem];
    [appMenuItem setSubmenu:appMenu];
    id window = [[[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:NSMakeRect(10, 10, 200, 200)
        styleMask:NSTitledWindowMask backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered defer:NO]
            autorelease];
    [window setTitle:appName];
    [window makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];
    [NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];
    [NSApp run];
    return 0;
}
```

It works well, except for one little problem: Immediately after the launch, menu is altered, but is inactive (clicking it does nothing). If I select some other application and then get back to that minimal one, menu starts working as expected.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Found it! It looks like the binary has to be in Contents/MacOS folder. If I move my binary into such folder, menu starts working as expected.

Comment: That more or less defeats the purpose of a CLI application, since what you've created is now an `.app` bundle.

Comment: The keyword for me is not "CLI" but "minimal"... and do that without XCode.

Comment: I’ll rephrase; you’ve no longer created a “minimal” Cocoa application consisting of only one file. You’ve got an application bundle, which requires your binary to be buried two directories deep. You never mentioned anything in your question about not using Xcode, although regardless the behavior you described originally is unexpected and you shouldn’t need to create an .app bundle as a work-around.

Comment: Actually, this is what is "minimal" working Cocoa application now. Minimal now requires creating minimal application bundle, otherwise menu does not work, because Apple broke something. Nobody said anything about "one file" :)OK, all that is nitpicking, anyway I believe my info could help somebody on the same quest (believe me, I was googling for 2 days before posting a question here).

Comment: Just a note. This happens equally on 2020 with Swift.

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem for minimal apps. They do not process events properly.

At this point (10.15.2 (19C57)) these are what it requires to work properly.

- Application bundle folder with `.app` extension. (maybe optional)
- `Contents/Info.plist` with `CFBundleIdentifier` value. (no other key is required)
- `Contents/MacOS/(your-executable)` file.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a bug in `macOS` somewhere above version **10.8.5**.

I tried the code (and similar variations within **10.13.6**) and they all failed in the way you've described. Compiling the same code and running on version **10.8.5** does not have the same behavior and the menu can be accessed normally as one would expect.

**Conclusion**:

> I would recommend reporting the behavior to Apple.

<sub>**Side Note**: You'll want to remove the `autorelease` portions of your code as `ARC` prohibits this and cannot be used with the latest Xcode SDK's.</sub>

Comment: Bug or not, 'regular' macos apps do not exhibit this behaviour. So there must be 'missing ingredient' there... WRT autorelease: It is my understanding ARC is optional. Is this no longer true?

Comment: The only thing i can figure is that the issue is within `setActivationPolicy`, and there’s no missing ingredient as it should work and simply doesn’t in more recent versions of the OS. Regarding `ARC`, yes it is optional, however, it’s recommended to utilize it if possible ( which is easy enough in your example ).

Answer (score 0):

looks like `NSApplicationActivationPolicyRegular` and `activateIgnoringOtherApps:` were missing according to https://github.com/rgl/minimal-cocoa-app

here is the updated code:

```
// cc -o min-cocoa min-cocoa.m -framework Cocoa
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        [NSApplication sharedApplication];
        id menubar = [NSMenu new];
        id appMenuItem = [NSMenuItem new];
        [menubar addItem:appMenuItem];
        [NSApp setMainMenu:menubar];
        id appMenu = [NSMenu new];
        id appName = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] processName];
        id quitTitle = [@"Quit " stringByAppendingString:appName];
        id quitMenuItem = [[NSMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:quitTitle action:@selector(terminate:) keyEquivalent:@"q"] ;
        [appMenu addItem:quitMenuItem];
        [appMenuItem setSubmenu:appMenu];
        id window = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:NSMakeRect(10, 10, 200, 200) styleMask:NSWindowStyleMaskTitled backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered defer:NO];
        [window setTitle:appName];
        [window cascadeTopLeftFromPoint:NSMakePoint(20,20)];
        [window makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];

        [NSApp setActivationPolicy:NSApplicationActivationPolicyRegular];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];
        });

        [NSApp run];
    }
    return 0;
}
```